# c# Cannot implicitly convert type '' to ''

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'am new in C#;
Please tell me what is bad;

I have an error with this MESSAGE:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Factory.ContactSite' to 'Factory.Site'"

MY code:

```
class SiteFactory {

    public enum SiteType {
        Contact, Gallery, Info, News
    }

    public static Site makeSite(SiteType type) {

        switch (type) {

            case SiteType.Contact:
                {
                    return new ContactSite();   //create new object
                }
            case SiteType.Info:
                {
                    return new InfoSite();     //create new object
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
class Site {

    public bool generate(String patch) {

        System.IO.FileStream f = new FileStream(patch, FileMode.Create);
        return true;
    }
}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------
main:

```
SiteFactory.makeSite(SiteFactory.SiteType.Contact).generate("file.txt");
```

class `ContactSite` is currently empty

Comment: Well presumably `ContactSite` doesn't derive from `Site`... it's hard to tell as you haven't shown the code. As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend that you learn about and start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Right. Is `ContactSite` supposed to be a kind of `Site`?

Comment: If the return type of the method is `Site`, then yes, any object returned from it needs to be either a `Site`, or of a class derived from `Site`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need to do is derive the classes `InfoSite` and `ContactSite` from `Site` like this:

```
public class ContactSite : Site
{

}

public class InfoSite : Site
{

}
```

when you call `makeSite` to get an Instance you would have to cast it into the right `type` like this:

```
InfoSite infSite = SiteFactory.makeSite(SiteFactory.SiteType.Contact) as InfoSite;
```